# find out the source of pivot tables

Tags: excel, excel-2010

i have got an excel file with pivot tables with external sources and also internal source. I need to know where the source is. any vba or menu options can indicate the source?.  excel 2010.

Answer (score 1):

In Excel 2010, click within the Pivot and watch in Options / Change Data Source.